# How to store multi-valued profile details?

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema, social-networking

I have many fields which are multi valued and not sure how to store them? if i do 3NF then there are many tables. For example: Nationality.

A person can have single or dual nationality. if dual this means it is a 1 to many. So i create a user table and a user_nationality table. (there is already a nationality lookup table). or i could put both nationalities into the same row like "American, German" then unserialize it on run-time. But then i dont know if i can search this? like if i search for only German people will it show up?

This is an example, i have over 30 fields which are multi-valued, so i assume i will not be creating 61 tables for this? 1 user table, 30 lookup tables to hold each multi-valued item's lookups and 30 tables to hold the user_ values for the multi valued items?

You must also keep in mind that some multi-valued fields group together like "colleges i have studied at" it has a group of fields such as college name, degree type, time line, etc. And a user can have 1 to many of these. So i assume i can create a separate table for this like user_education with these fields, but lets assume one of these fields is also fixed list multi-valued like college campuses i visited then we will end up in a never ending chain of FK tables which isn't a good design for social networks as the goal is it put as much data into as fewer tables as possible for performance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to stop using a SQL table. This what NoSQL is deigned for. Check out CouchDB or Mongo. There each value can be stored as a full structure - so this whole problem could be reduced to a single (not-really-)table.

The downside of pretty much any SQL based solution is that it will be slow. Either slow when fetching a single user - a massive JOIN statement won't execute quickly or slow when searching (if you decide to store these values as serialized).

Comment: Well nosql solutions are a new area, have to learn their syntax, etc so chances of errors and time delays go up. Down the road yes that is the plan but for now i want to get a launch quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep using SQL, you will need to create these tables. you will need to decide on how far you are willing to go, and impose limitations on the system (such as only being able to specify one campus).

As far as nationality goes, if you will only require two nationalities (worst-case scenario), you could consider a second nationality field (Nationality and Nationality2) to account for this. Of course this only applies to fields with a small maximum number of different values.

Answer (score 0):

If your user table has a lot of related attributes, then one possibility is to create one attributes table with rows like (user_id, attribute_name, attribute_value). You can store all your attributes to one table. You can use this table to fetch attributes for given users, also search by attribute names and values.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at ORM which will map your objects to a database automatically.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#PHP

Answer (score 0):

> This is an example, i have over 30
> fields which are multi-valued, so i
> assume i will not be creating 61
> tables for this?

You're right that 61 is the maximum number of tables, but in reality it'll likely be less, take your own example:

> "colleges i have studied at"
>
> "college campuses i visited"

In this case you'll probably only have one "collage" table, so there would be four tables in this layout, not five.

I'd say don't be afraid of using lots of tables if the data set you're modelling is large - just make sure you keep an up to date ERD so you don't get lost!  Also, don't get caught up too much in the "link table" paradigm - "link tables" can be "entities" in their own rights, for example you could think of the "colleges i have studied at" link table as an "collage enrolments" table instead, give it it's own primary key, and store each of the times you pay your course fees as rows in a (linked) "collage enrolment payments" table.

Comment: By link tables you mean lookup tables?

Comment: No, I mean a table with 2 foreign keys, i.e. "collage enrolments" links "people" to "collages"